# superclass mismatch for class FailedExampleNotification when running rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am not sure what FailedExampleNotification is?? or why I am getting this error? It is now allowing me to successfully run rspec

```
An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: require 'rspec/rails'

TypeError:
  superclass mismatch for class FailedExampleNotification
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00004 seconds (files took 1.69 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Comment: From the logs it seems like there is circular require, Could you please share your spec_helper.rb file?

Comment: have you fixed this issue? would like to share?